# XAMPP won't run php

Tags: php, xampp

I've installed XAMPP on a 32-bit windows xp machine. Their splash page at localhost looks fine, but i can't get my own php echo tests to run. They only display the code, not the page itself. I've tried putting my files in different places in their directory hoping something will work. I've also tried other free servers with no luck, but have since removed them. Where(?) is localhost on my machine? any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: post your apache config, your php code is not being run through the interpreter.

Comment: Light years too vague. We are not an arbitrary support helpline, let alone one that can _read minds_. We answer **specific** questions about pieces of code.

Comment: BTW `localhost` **is** your machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAMPP usually stores the web-accessible files in an `htdocs` folder. Find this and prepend `http://localhost/` where `local/path/to/htdocs` would be, and if XAMPP is running, it should work.

So a file (in Windows) named and found in `c:\xampp\htdocs\test.php` would be `http://localhost/test.php`.

See: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#startpage

Comment: do you get a medal for answering a closed question?

Comment: A medal? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: i guess i meant a badge. thanks  for your help!