# I just installed XAMPP but PhP is not running

Tags: php, apache

I think everything is correct. The htdocs directory is correct etc.

I tried to run simple file

```
test hello
<? phpinfo ();
echo "hello world";
?>
```

Result of

http://localhost/test.php

is

test hello

So the PhP part is just ignored.

I checked some possible solutions here
[php file is not running using xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970131/php-file-is-not-running-using-xampp)

However the problem is not quite the same. In most cases the problem is in the format of the PhP or some problems with the PhP code. In my ase the PhP it self doesn't run even when runnign simple codes.

[XAMPP won't run php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135381/xampp-wont-run-php) says that the problem is the location of htdocs. It's not. I know that I got the right directory because xampp display the non PhP part of the code correctly.

I also checked some similar questions on this forum. I saw for example that

`Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"`

exist in httpd.conf and inside it I saw

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

So everything should be up up.

By the way if I look at the source, this is what I see:

```
test hello
<? phpinfo ();
echo "hello world";
?>
```

So it seems that xampp just display the php source code rather than executing it.

Comment: XAMPP control panel shows any error messages?

Comment: Look at your page source in the browser. Do you see the code rendered there? You are using PHP's short open tag `<?` which is likely disabled.  Use `<?php` rather than `<?`.

Comment: Okay interesting. Yes the code shows up.

Comment: Have you installed PHP? :D @SharenEayrs

Comment: try check your system services if apache is running

Comment: it works. I used the short sign of PhP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php tag is wrong, opening tag should be 
`<?php`

Comment: That is precisely what the problem is.

Comment: looks like I am confused between <?php and <? phpinfo. I thought I am using the long tag already.

Comment: `phpinfo()` is a function that outputs information about your PHP installation. It is altogether different than the PHP open tag (`<?php`).